# Single Responsibility Principle and Projects (Visual Studio/C#) -- how do you organize your projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, single-responsibility-principle

I've been trying to really understand SRP and SOLID and completely understand why people apply it.  I'm still trying to master the "art" of SRP myself.  Getting into it, the advice I understand the most is, "Write what the purpose of your class is.  If the sentence has the words and, but, except, then it's doing too much.  So I might have written a class called "ActiveDirectoryHelper" (smelly, i know) that has CreateComputerObject, FindComputerObject and DeleteComputerObject.  I think this should be broken into three separate classes, no?

But more importantly, if I applied SRP religiously, won't I get dozens and dozens of class .cs files in my Visual Studio/C# project?  If so and if that's the way it has to be, how do you organize your projects?

Many thanks

Comment: This is highly subjective, no right answer, and also personal preference bias (I expect this question to be closed as not helpful by those with the power). Personally I try to keep my classes small with scoped/specific functionality as it makes them easier to test; so yes you can end up with a lot of simple/testable classes but end up with a complex setup (that is where dependency injection comes in useful).

Answer (score 2):

> So I might have written a class called "ActiveDirectoryHelper" (smelly, i know) that has CreateComputerObject, FindComputerObject and DeleteComputerObject. I think this should be broken into three separate classes, no?

According to SRP class should have only one reason to change. For example, if you anticipate that at some point you would want to change creation logic for ComputerObject and this change will not affect Find* and Delete* methods you should extract CreateComputerObject to a separate class: ComputerObjectFactory.

> But more importantly, if I applied SRP religiously, won't I get dozens and dozens of class .cs files in my Visual Studio/C# project?

This is a surprisingly frequent question/argument that you hear in MS land where some people prefer giant 'god classes' and use code regions for organization. Large number of classes is usually a very good sign. Most of the time it makes your code more readable, testable and organized. After all C# is an *object*-oriented language, so don't be afraid to create more classes.

> If so and if that's the way it has to be, how do you organize your projects?

Use namespaces and folders for example?

Comment: So while I live in MS land with C#, I hate huge, god classes, etc.  I also think that Visual Studio helps you ALOT navigate all the small classes so I'm good with smaller classes.  However, some peers have suggested that I have TOO many classes.  So a big part of my question for those that practice SRP in VS is:  "How do you organize your projects?"  I see see your point on namespaces and folders...thanks for the answer!